# OSError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/home/ahmed/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python'

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

l'm under ubuntu 16.04. l have installed opencv for `python 3` (**3.6 and 3.5)**. Now , l need also to install it for python2.7.
To do so, l've followed the following link :
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

l have successfully run all the steps until :

```
mkvirtualenv cv
```

when l run it l get the following error  :

```
 mkvirtualenv cv
Using base prefix '/home/ahmed/anaconda3'
New python executable in /home/ahmed/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1231, in install_python
    shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
OSError: [Errno 40] Too many levels of symbolic links: '/home/ahmed/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python'
```

Comment: Use anaconda environment or miniconda as an alternate to virtualenv

Comment: @bigbounty how  can l use that  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install anaconda,

1.Download anaconda from https://www.continuum.io/downloads

2.Move to the directory where you downloaded the file.

3.bash Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh for python2  OR

bash Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh for python3

Create a anaconda environment

`conda create -n yourenv python=x.x anaconda`

`source activate yourenv`